# How to correctly draw an amplifier in tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, circuitikz

Im trying to do in tikz the next amplifier schematic:
[image]

But Im stuck here
[image]

I dont know why the source works for a pin and the other takes the line and write in the image. And the stealth is moved to the right, when at the beginning there were in the right site over the + and - inputs.

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}

\usepackage[siunitx]{circuitikz}

\ctikzset{bipoles/capacitor/height/.initial=.4854}
\ctikzset{bipoles/capacitor/width/.initial=.1}

\begin{document}%
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw
  (0,0) node[fd op amp] (opamp) {} node[left] {\\}
 
   (opamp.-) node[circ] {} to[$text1$,*-*] ++(-1.5,0) node[ocirc] {} node[left] {\(v_p\)}
  (opamp.+) node[circ] {} to[$text2$, l=\(C_s\)] ++(-0.8,0) node[ocirc] {} node[left] {\(v_n\)}
  (opamp.out -) node[circ] {} -- ++(0,0)
 to[battery, l_=\SI{}{-V_{cc}}, invert] ++(0,-2) node[cground](GND){};

(opamp.out +) node[circ] {} -- ++(0,0) 
 to[battery, l_=\SI{}{+V_{cc}}] (0,2) node[cground](GND){};
  
\draw [-stealth](-3,1) -- (-1.5,1)node[pos=0.7, above]{$i_{P}$};

\draw [-stealth](-3,-1) -- (-1.5,-1)node[pos=0.7, below]{$i_{N}$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You did end the path (there is a `;`) but afterwards continue to specify things that should be drawn without putting `\draw` in front of it.

Comment: thats one part to correct, thanks.

Comment: Another issue you got is the usage of `\SI`, that is *totally* the wrong usage of that command. If you want upright symbols in maths use `\mathrm`. `\SI` is to print numbers which have a unit, so something like 3 W (three Watt) would be typeset using `\SI{3}{\watt}` (but note that with `siunitx` version 3 even that wouldn't be the preferred method, better would nowadays be `\qty{3}{\watt}`).

Comment: Yet another issue is the usage of `$text1$` in the option of `to`, that isn't supported by both `circuitikz` and Ti*k*Z, afaik (and I have no idea what you want to achieve with it, maybe you wanted to use `l=$text$`?).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The following draws the upper circuit completely. The only thing I didn't bother with was using arrows next to the shorts to show currents.

Everything is positioned relative to each other and using coordinates, so this should be quite easy to customize.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14]{standalone}

\usepackage[american]{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw
    (0,0) coordinate(vp-)
      to[short,o-o] ++(1,0)   coordinate(vn-)
      to[short,-*]  ++(2,0)   coordinate(gnd)
    node[ground]{}
      to[short,-*]  ++(1.2,0) coordinate(vcc)
      to[short,-o]  ++(2,0)   coordinate(vo-)
    (gnd)
      to[battery,-o,v=$-V_{\mathrm{CC}}$] ++(0,1.5)
      to[short,i_=$I_{\mathrm{C}-}$]      ++(0,0.5)
    node[op amp, yscale=-1, anchor=up](amp){}
    (amp.down)
      to[short,-o,i<_=$I_{\mathrm{C}+}$]  ++(0,0.5)
      to[short] ++(0,0.2) coordinate(tmp)
      to[short] (tmp-|vcc)
      to[battery,v=$+V_{\mathrm{CC}}$]   (vcc)
    (amp.+)
      to[short,-o, i<_=$i_{\mathrm{P}}$] (amp.+-|vp-)
      to[open, v=$v_{\mathrm{P}}$]       (vp-)
    (amp.-)
      to[short,-o, i<_=$i_{\mathrm{N}}$] (amp.--|vn-)
      to[open, v=$v_{\mathrm{N}}$]       (vn-)
    (amp.out)
      to[short,-o, i=$i_{\mathrm{O}}$]   (amp.out-|vo-)
      to[open, v^=$v_{\mathrm{O}}$]      (vo-)
    ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What wasnt working the two battery's? or why one work and the other not? Thanks superb figure!!

Comment: @riccs_0x I posted a few comments to your question to list the issues I spotted. But honestly, I didn't look much at your code before creating this answer, I just looked at your circuit and recreated it how I'd have done it.

Comment: Thanks, its very instructive!!!